flink + hudi with dfs catalog , jdbc connector not works
Im useing hudi with flink. I have a mysql table named stu4.
Without catalog, it works. but with dfs catalog, I cant read any data from source table.
the table in hudi is :
create table stu4(
  id bigint not null,
  name string,
  school string,
  PRIMARY KEY (id) NOT ENFORCED
) with (
  'connector' = 'jdbc',
  'url' = 'jdbc:mysql://hadoop2:3306/test',
  'username' = 'root',
  'password' = '*******',
  'table-name' = 'stu4'
);

without catalog:
select * from stu4;

2024-10-22 17:26:12,202 WARN  org.apache.flink.yarn.configuration.YarnLogConfigUtil        [] - The configuration directory ('/bigdata/flink/conf') already contains a LOG4J config file.If you want to use logback, then please delete or rename the log configuration file.
2024-10-22 17:26:12,223 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.DefaultNoHARMFailoverProxyProvider [] - Connecting to ResourceManager at hadoop1/10.211.55.20:8032
2024-10-22 17:26:12,223 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor                  [] - No path for the flink jar passed. Using the location of class org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor to locate the jar
2024-10-22 17:26:12,231 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor                  [] - Found Web Interface hadoop1:43613 of application 'application_1729525785030_0003'.

+----+----------------------+--------------------------------+
| op |                   id |                           name |
+----+----------------------+--------------------------------+
| +I |                    3 |                              1 |
| +I |                    4 |                              2 |
| +I |                    5 |                              3 |
+----+----------------------+--------------------------------+
Received a total of 3 rows

with catalog:
select * from stu4;

2024-10-22 17:30:25,787 WARN  org.apache.flink.yarn.configuration.YarnLogConfigUtil        [] - The configuration directory ('/bigdata/flink/conf') already contains a LOG4J config file.If you want to use logback, then please delete or rename the log configuration file.
2024-10-22 17:30:25,803 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.DefaultNoHARMFailoverProxyProvider [] - Connecting to ResourceManager at hadoop1/10.211.55.20:8032
2024-10-22 17:30:25,804 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor                  [] - No path for the flink jar passed. Using the location of class org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor to locate the jar
2024-10-22 17:30:25,807 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor                  [] - Found Web Interface hadoop1:43613 of application 'application_1729525785030_0003'.

+----+----------------------+--------------------------------+
| op |                   id |                           name |
+----+----------------------+--------------------------------+
Received a total of 0 row


catalog config is:
CREATE CATALOG hoodie_catalog
  WITH (
    'type'='hudi',
    'catalog.path' = '/tmp/hudi_catalog',
    'mode'='dfs'
  );

USE CATALOG hoodie_catalog;

